# Doubts on rtabmap stereo_odometry parameters and feature visualization

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, rtabmap-odometry, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am trying to tune the many parameters of RtabMap, in particular the ones of the stereo_odometry node.

I have some doubts: [in this paper](https://introlab.3it.usherbrooke.ca/mediawiki-introlab/images/7/7a/Labbe18JFR_preprint.pdf)  it's written that "for F2F (Odom/Strategy=1), optical flow is done directly on GFTT features without having to extract descriptors".

My question is: if I change the parameter Vis/CorType to 0, so the correspondences computation approach is Features Matching, which approach is used? features matching or optical flow?

Similarly If I change the parameter Vis/FeatureType to use different features than GFTT, is this parameter valid, or with F2F approach the only parameter used is the one described in the paper?

Also another question: there is a way to view at the detected features? My idea is to plot the corners  (for F2F) and wordsValues (for F2M) points in the [OdomInfo message](http://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/rtabmap_ros/html/msg/OdomInfo.html) but I don't know if there is a better way.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 with ROS noetic and rtabmap built from source

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/410498/doubts-on-rtabmap-stereo_odometry-parameters-and-feature-visualization/) by [AlessioParmeggiani](https://answers.ros.org/users/94489/alessioparmeggiani/) on ROS Answers with karma: 165 on 2022-12-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

If you set `Vis/CorType=0`, feature matching will be done. In the paper, we compared `Odom/Strategy=0` (F2M)+`Vis/CorType=0` (Feature matching) with `Odom/Strategy=1` (F2F)+`Vis/CorType=1` (Optical Flow). When we set `Vis/FeatureType` to 6, it is GFTT keypoint + BRIEF descriptor. For `Vis/CorType=1`, the descriptors are just not extracted on GFTT features, optical flow is done instead. All approaches in `Vis/FeatureType` have a detector+descriptor, the later is not used in case of optical flow.

Look at the F2M or F2F sections in the [OdomInfo](http://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/rtabmap_ros/html/msg/OdomInfo.html) message, you will see the features are published.

If you use rtabmapviz with `subscribe_odom_info`, you will see the features over the images in Odometry view.

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2022-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AlessioParmeggiani](https://answers.ros.org/users/94489/alessioparmeggiani/) on 2022-12-15**:
Thank you for the explanation!   :)

I tried to use rtabmapviz but I didn't find some explanation about what the yellow and green dots represent on the image, moreover if I use it the odometry gets lost, maybe it's because by using it the computer slows down, the stereo_odometry node can't compute the odometry fast enough and so it loses some frames.

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2022-12-15**:
"gets lost" -> mostly depend of your kind of camera. If you have narrow FOV with motion blur (rolling shutter), it will easily get lost. See also Lost Odometry section here https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap/wiki/Kinect-mapping#lostodometry